# In an array, how do i update the value so when one item is chosen, the stock goes down?

Tags: java

I have an array setup and another class in this program that gives me a getInStock to give me the current value in the array.  I'm trying to subtract one of the stock once the person using the program enters in a number for the item being used.  I want it to then update the number in the array in case it is used again.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // create the stdin object (to use the keyboard)
            Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
            int itemSelected = 0;   // Item ID selected by user, 0 for not available
            int itemIndex = 0;      // selected index into array of items

            // display items in the arrays using the toString method
            System.out.printf ("%-4.4s %6.6s %-11.11s\n", "Item", "Price", "Description");
            for (Item b : ITEM_LIST) { System.out.println(b); }       


            System.out.println ("\nSelect an item by its item number. Enter 0 to quit");
            do {
                try {
                    System.out.printf ("item #%d: ", shoppingCartCount+1);
                    itemSelected = stdin.nextInt( );       // read line from keyboard
                    if (itemSelected == 0)
                        continue;   // exit the loop

                    // Search ITEM_LIST looking for the user's requested itemID
                    for (itemIndex=0; itemIndex<ITEM_LIST.length; itemIndex++)

                        if (itemSelected == ITEM_LIST[itemIndex].getItemID()){

                            if (ITEM_LIST[itemIndex].getInStock()<1){
                                System.out.println("Item is not in stock try later");                      
                            }
                            break;  // it was found, itemIndex = position in the LIST
                        }
                    if (itemIndex == ITEM_LIST.length){  // reached the end and not found                
                        System.out.println("Item is not available");
                    }
                    if (shoppingCartCount==9 ) {
                        shoppingCart[shoppingCartCount] = ITEM_LIST[itemIndex];
                        shoppingCartCount++;  // keep track of items in the cart 
                        System.out.println("Your cart is full.");
                        break;
                    }                
                    else {  // The item was found                       
                        shoppingCart[shoppingCartCount] = ITEM_LIST[itemIndex];
                        shoppingCartCount++;  // keep track of items in the cart            
                    }
                }   //end of try
                catch (InputMismatchException |  StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println ("Illegal selection. Try again"); 
                }  
            } while (itemSelected != 0);   // loop until a '0' is entered

            // display the shopping cart
            System.out.println("\n\nThank you for shopping at Shop-azon");
            double total=0;
            for (int i=0; i<shoppingCartCount; i++) {
                System.out.println(shoppingCart[i]);
                total += shoppingCart[i].getPrice();            
            }
            System.out.println(shoppingCartCount + " items in your cart");
            System.out.printf("Your total is $%.2f\n\n", total);       
        } // end of main()
```

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is `ITEM_LIST`, `Item` - what problems are you facing?

Comment: Item_ list is the array of everything in the store.  Item is another class in the program that send the prices, stock and item ID to the main program I posted.  Everything else in the program works fine.  The problem I am having, is getting the number of items in stock to decrease when one is chosen by the user

Comment: Huh? I can not see where in this jumble of code that you are trying to decrease the stock item count

Comment: On the try{.  On the for loop

Comment: So after this `if (ITEM_LIST[itemIndex].getInStock()<1){...}` ? As I have hinted before, you have not shown any of this `Item` code, so how on earth can we tell you what methods to call?  If you want people to spend time on your questions at least think about what information they need.

Comment: I was trying too keep the code to a minimum because i didn't want to add five different class code for each of the different types of items that I am using in the array.   I see that was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the use case you have explained , like you want to remove the number when you are using it and later update it better use Queue in Java and use functions like pop() , push() , seek()  for help you can see this

Click [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-interface-java/)!